# Any method that I can refer to simulate 3D scanning and flow through extruder in MATLAB?

Tags: nozzle

I would like to simulate the 3D scanning process with a specific wavelength and swath width of the beam, etc. and then reproduce the image, the whole of which in MATLAB. I also want to simulate the flow of filler material through the extruder.

Can I refer to any articles or formulae?